# Using part of url as gettable variable, not a wildcard

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server, url-rewriting

I am trying to `$_GET` part of a rewritten url but it only seems to work when I use a wildcard `(.*)`.

So this works for me:

```
RewriteRule         ^info/(.*)$ _extern/web/listing.php?alias=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But this doesn't :

```
RewriteRule         ^winkels$ _extern/web/listing.php?alias=$1 [QSA,L]
```

On info/winkels I can retrieve the alias and it shows 'winkels' when I echo it, but on /winkels it's empty.

Why?

Comment: To what request url do you apply that rule, `/info/wínkels` or `/winkels`?

Comment: @arkascha To test I first tried it with `info/winkels` which worked, but I want `/winkels` and when I tried that, it stops working. I just want to be able to read the alias `winkels` when I am on the page `winkels`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to actually capture the part of the URL you want to hand over.

Have a try using that rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(winkels)$ _extern/web/listing.php?alias=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Note: without the capturing brackets `$1` will simply be empty...

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know it also worked like that, makes sense.